# Bounty question and daily reputation limit?

Tags: discussion, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

Is answering a bounty question immune to the daily reputation limit?

Answer (score 14):

Marc's answer used to be right, but as of March 2010, it is no longer correct. Bounties are now completely, totally, 100% immune to the rep cap. See [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/21/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) for the full story:

> accepted answers and bounties were only *partially* immune to the rep cap before depending on the time of day you earned them, but they are *fully* immune now.

Answer (score 11):

Yes and no.

It depends on "when". If you get the bounty **after** you've maxed, then yes; it is immune.

But if you get awarded a bounty at 2am (server time), then yes, you get the bounty, but you'll simply "max" sooner.

i.e. (sequence)

- 15 upvotes; 15 upvotes; 100 bounty => 300 points
- 15 upvotes; +100 bounty; 15 upvotes => 250 points
- 100 bounty; 15 upvotes; 15 upvotes => 200 points

It is (in some ways) very frustrating to get for example a 150 bounty first thing in the morning (server-time). But hey, you still get the bounty!

Comment: That's great to know. I joined SO yesterday, and answered a question with a bounty (I had already participated a bit without an account a few months ago). I made 160 rep today (am I addicted yet?)...

So if I read your reply correctly, if I get the bounty granted today, I will get the whole +100 rep anyway, not 40 (just enough to make me hit roof). Thanks!

Comment: @Nicolás: correct. But if they accept *tomorrow* 00:00 UTC, then you get the 100 but it counts towards the limit as usual.