# Is there a delay after bounty expires before the top-voted answer is automatically selected?

Tags: support, bounties

I provided an answer to [this bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174448/jquery-animate-problems), which became the top-voted answer with 13 upvotes and 2 downvotes.  My answer was posted after the bounty was posted.

The OP never accepted an answer, and the bounty expired about thirty minutes ago, but I haven't been awarded any rep and nothing has been marked as accepted.  Is there a delay I'm not aware of?

[According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions/4532#4532):

> You [the asker] do not accept an answer. Any answer that was a) **provided after the bounty period started** and b) **has 2 or more upvotes** is automatically accepted after 7 days. The bounty is subtracted from your [the asker's] reputation. The answerer is awarded half the bounty amount.

---

If this is a new solution to the [bounties contribute to daily rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/bounty-question-and-daily-reputation-limit/9949#9949) problem that people have been complaining about for some time, then that's fine.  (i.e. if you only award the bounty just before midnight UTC.)  But I can't find anything here on MSO that implies this.

---

**Update**: Looks like the bounty was awarded on the next hour (21:00 UTC).  So maybe it's an hourly process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible that there is a delay so that it only checks expired bounties every period or so. I won a bounty a day or so ago and I was almost certain that it awarded me the bounty once the server time flipped over to the next day. Your results may vary.

Comment: hmm.. hopefully it is just *before* the server time flips over... if so, maybe it is a solution to the "bounties contribute to daily rep cap limit" problem that people have been complaining about for a while

Comment: I've usually seen it immediately *after* the server time flips over... which is indeed irritating.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Ditto.

Comment: my bounty was awarded at 21:00 UTC, so it looks like it might be an hourly task.  maybe someone should put in a feature-request that any cron jobs which give rep should be run at xx:55 instead of xx:00, to avoid capping someone's rep prematurely?

Comment: I don't think any request dealing with rep (directly or indirectly) will be acknowledged at this point.

Comment: @Ian: Agreed.  Apparently if you're a SO developer, you're under the impression that the rep system is flawless.  The rest of us are just greedy repwhores complaining about perceived shortcomings.

Comment: FYI -- there still appears to be a delay til the top of the following hour before the bounty is applied when auto-accepted.